# Spring autowiring issue with CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Out of curosity i have the following question,i have one spring boot application running using commnad line runner where kinesis consumers would be running :

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        public class FleetMessagingKCLApplication  implements CommandLineRunner{

            //Command line runner
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                kinesisconsumers.startConsumers();

            }   
        }
```

I have one service locator bean in the MAIN class(mentioned below) having interface Processor Factory for Factory Pattern implementation:

```
        @Bean
        public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorForMessageTransformation() {  
                ServiceLocatorFactoryBean slfb = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
                slfb.setServiceLocatorInterface(ProcessorFactory.class);
                return slfb;
            }
```

But was not able to autowire the  ProcessFactory  in any of the classes,but after moving the service locator bean bean into another java class declared with Component, autowiring worked as expected.

Was thing someting related to using command line runner that i was not able to autowire?